# Flask file is sent as attachment only. BUG?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to send a file from flask but it is always being sent as an attachment.
My HTML side is this

```
<a target="_blank" href="/view/attachment/8948bc6ca00cd1741351ff726f.png"><i style="color:green; cursor:pointer;" class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a>
```

My flask

```
@app.route('/view/attachment/asdasddas/<file>', methods=['GET', "POST"])
def view_attachment(file):
            return send_file(f'/attachments/{file}',
                     mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                     attachment_filename=file,
                     download_name=file,
                     as_attachment=False,
                     cache_timeout=-1)
```

But it is always getting downloaded. I want to to be viewed in a new tab and not to download the file directly.

Comment: that is a browser configuration for .png, not related to the app at all

Comment: But it is the same for pdf also. I tried PDF @azro

Comment: The browser is permitted to do what it pleases with the files. You can ask it nicely to treat things as attachments, but you can't really ask for the reverse. If you want things displayed in a particular way, that's what HTML is for.